# Does all the atoms have same mass with respect to their molar mass ? Is there any factor that increases its inertia?

Tags: mass, atomic-physics

Does all the atoms have same mass (with respect to their molar mass). For example: 1 mole of Uranium 234 has a gram molecular mass of 234 grams, But is there any factors that increases its mass ?. Obviously its not possible to decrease the inertia (I guess), But is there any factors that increases the inertia (mass)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all atoms have the same mass. A neutral carbon atom has 6 protons and 6 neutrons whereas a neutral oxygen atom has 8 protons and 8 neutrons. So the carbon atom has a different mass to oxygen atom. So obviously no, atoms do not all have the same mass. It is possible to decrease the inertia - just decrease the mass. If you want to increase inertia - increase the mass. There are lots of resources out there on this question - try putting more effort into researching your own question, that way you won't get negative votes.

Comment: Not all carbon atoms have 6 neutrons, nor do all oxygen atoms have 8 neutrons.

Comment: i am referring to carbon-12 and oxygen-16 as a typical example of neutral atoms. Yes, there are isotopes.